# Turn off responsive for small resolution devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How to turn off responsive design for small resolution devices? Responsive looks terrible when trying to access with phone. More at screenshots.
[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccHxd.jpg)
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwki6.jpg)

Comment: use class="row" instead of "row-fluid".

Comment: are you using a seperate style sheet for adaptive/responsive control?

Comment: > Vector
Yeah. Usual bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: The question is confusing because the "responsive design" is what allows you to apply different rules on different resolutions. What would you display on mobile devices ? And tablets ? You might look into removing the [responsive design support](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: @dave its work, but not well as i expect.

Comment: @Sherbrow i want to display on mobile devices fixed width, like 1024x600. For example: if resolution lower than 1024x600 site must display as 1024x600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i would do it is to restrict the responsive style sheet from loading on smaller devices eg

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />`